# How can I call async method from constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, async-await

I need to call a `async` method from my `Form1` constructor. Since a constructor can't have a return type, I can't add a `async void`. I read that [static constructor](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0d24419e-36ad-4157-abb5-3d9e6c5dacf1/constructor-invoke-async-method) can be `async` but I need to call methods from constructor that aren't `static`, such as `InitializeComponent()` (since it's the Form's constructor).

The class is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //some stuff
    await myMethod();
}
```

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261173/c-sharp-start-async-method-within-object-constructor-bad-practice) one too but I still don't know how to implement this (in my case) since the method still requires to use `async`.

Comment: Read the [Async OOP](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-0-introduction.html) from Stephen Clearly.

Comment: FYI, that link up there actually appears to be calling for async static factory methods as an alternate approach to static constructors using async.  In the article it says static constructors *can't* be async

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't do this in the constructor but in the loaded event of the window instead.
You can mark the loaded eventhandler as async.

Comment: Don't you just end up with an `async void WindowLoaded()`, then? Aren't we supposed to avoid `async void`? What would be the difference between just calling a `private async void MyMethodAsync()` from the constructor?

Comment: Event handlers are a special case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers

Answer (score 7):

You can use a static method that returns an instance of your form

```
public class TestForm : Form
{
    private TestForm()
    {
    }

    public static async Task<TestForm> Create()
    {
        await myMethod();
        return new TestForm();
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I have a question on this. To call `Create()` shouldn't I do `await Create()` if so, I do need mark the constructor as `async` isn't?

Comment: @Jack Yes you will call it as `await TestForm.Create()`, but constructor doesn't have to be *async*

Comment: Limitations of this answer: 1) `myMethod` has to be static; has no access to instance members of TestForm. 2) only helps if calling code is in an `async` context. #1 can be fixed by `var it = new TestForm(); await it.myMethod(); return it;`

Answer (score 2):

My sample is to call student details from page constructor

1- the calling of navigation page

```
    void Handle_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Student _student = (Student)e.Item;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Student_Details(_student.ID));

    }
```

2 - the details page

```
public partial class Student_Details : ContentPage
{
    public Student_Details(int id)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Task.Run(async () => await getStudent(id));
    }

    public async Task<int> getStudent(int id)
    {
        Student _student;
        SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteDatabase();
        _student = await db.getStudent(id);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While common advice dictates you generally shouldn't do it in the constructor, you can do the following, which I have used in apps, such as console apps, where I need to call some existing async code:

```
DetailsModel details = null; // holds the eventual result
var apiTask = new Task(() => details = MyService.GetDetailsAsync(id).Result); // creates the task with the call on another thread
apiTask.Start(); // starts the task - important, or you'll spin forever
Task.WaitAll(apiTask); // waits for it to complete
```

Philip is correct that, if you can avoid doing this in a constructor, you should.

Answer (score -5):

`Task.Run(async () => await YourAsyncMethod());`

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work. For more information read [How To Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).